# Ruby not starting on mac os x

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

when I try to use ruby with the terminal, nothing happens.
The last days I've used it and everything worked but it doesn't anymore.
I installed rvm and the 1.9.3 version of ruby.
It works when I launch a script with `ruby myscript.rb`, and I tried installing rails but when I type `gem install rails` I get an error: 
`/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194 in PATH, mode 040777`

As there is no output I don't know where the problem comes from. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
`rvm info`

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194:

system:
uname:       "Darwin romain.home 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.14.1 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
updated:      "1 day 11 hours 59 minutes 3 seconds ago"

ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "1.9.3p194"
date:         "2012-04-20"
platform:     "x86_64-darwin11.3.0"
patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]"

homes:
gem:          "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
ruby:         "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

binaries:
ruby:         "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
gem:          "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
rake:         "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH:         "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/romainberger/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
GEM_HOME:     "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
GEM_PATH:     "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Users/romainberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
IRBRC:        "/Users/romainberger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

`gem info` gives me:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
Unknown command info
```

And to launch ruby I just type `ruby`

Comment: Have you tried removing write permissions for others on that directory?

Comment: I think this warning doesn't related to the problem

Comment: @ Emil Vikström How can i do that ?

Comment: @Flexoid I don't know, but it appeared after installing rvm, that's why I posted it

Comment: Try using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) instead.

Comment: romainberger, with the `chmod` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the gem warning use:

```
chmod -R go-w /Users/romainberger/.rvm/
```

It will recursively remove write right for group and others (keeps write for user).

You can check for RVM related resurces on RVM site: https://rvm.io/

Comment: Thanks, fixed a part of my problem

Comment: so what is the remaining part of problem - this was not clear from your question, maybe open a new ticket?

Comment: The problem is that when I just type `ruby` to launch it nothing happens.

Comment: please include `rvm info`, `gem info` and the command you run