# Sass: Listen has fallen back to polling

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to use sass, and it gives me an error when I compile my files.
It works (the .scss files are compiled into .css files) but then I get this warning:
`WARNING: Listen has fallen back to polling, learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#fallback.`

Of course I read the link given, but except rebooting the os, I don't know what the other solutions are.
If needed here are some informations about the versions:
ruby: 1.9.3
sass: 3.1.19
everything on a mac.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks

(oh, and I still have this problem => [Ruby not starting on mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873759/ruby-not-starting-on-mac-os-x) )

**EDIT**
I found the solution ... listen was not installed (yes I am ashamed).

So you can ignore my question, but if you have an idea the old one about ruby I am listening (no pun intended)

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly the same, so your edit was very useful! ;-)

Comment: You should write that edit as as an answer (event despite the shame :) since that is the answer.

Comment: Even two years later, the question still helps people :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try:

```
 sudo gem install  listen
```

Followed by:

```
 gem install --version '~> 0.8.8' rb-inotify
```

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo gem install --version '0.4.7' listen`

Comment: You'd need sudo for the second one, too.

Answer (score 0):

Default install of Debian 7 only has `ruby` 1.8.7 which is not supported by new versions of `listen`. [A Github ticket](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/798) implies that `listen` 1.3.1 is last supported version for pre 1.9 version of `ruby`.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]

$ sudo gem install --version '1.3.1' listen
```

`gem` should pull `rb-inotify` as a dependency of `listen`.